# Best Fit (place) the cuboid object to instead of another cuboid object in c#/unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In scene, There are 12 known edges and 8 points. This shape is like cuboid shaped So, I have another prefab that another cuboid object. I want to place my cuboid prefab with another old cuboid in the same direction, same position, same scale and same rotation.

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/6/955065f84b3c3ae442f0be8a3e2ee48d-full.png

First cuboid is creating in run time named referenceCuboid
New object is  in my prefab named cuboidObj

I found position with edges's help. and I placed  object to center of referenceCuboid.

```
{  
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y, z);


    //rotation
    Quaternion rotation = cuboidObj.transform.rotation;
    Quaternion.LookRotation(edgeX.transform.position); //edges are a Cylinder

    cuboidObj.transform.rotation = rotation;

    //Scale
    Vector3 size = obj.transform.lossyScale;

    // (edgeX, edgeY, edgeZ) are reference edges in referenceCuboid
    size.z = edgeZ.transform.lossyScale.z;
    size.x = (size.z* obj.transform.localScale.y) / obj.transform.lossyScale.x;
    size.y = (size.z* obj.transform.localScale.y) / obj.transform.lossyScale.y;
    size.z = (size.z* obj.transform.localScale.y) / obj.transform.lossyScale.z;
    cuboidObj.transform.localScale = size;


    obj.transform.localScale = size;

    cuboidObj = Instantiate(cuboidObj, position, Quaternion.identity);

}
```

I can't scale, rotate  new cuboid object to referenceCuboid. I tried x y z edges and x,y,z axis of new cuboid object but no correct result. wrong alignment

Comment: Why not create the cube in editor mode, align it with the prefab, and record the TRS data.

Comment: I created a cube in editor mode named cuboidObject. I am creating reference cuboid(with corner points and edges) in real time. It is dynamic. @shingo

Comment: Since I don't know how do you create the cuboid, I suggest you to solve the alignment problem by creating the cuboid in editor mode then move / rotate / resize it manually. this may help you understand why the alignment is wrong during runtime.

Comment: But the main problem that I need to instantiate a new mycuboidObject in run time . Need to calculate rotate, scale based referenceCuboid object.